# How to find the max date in an text?

Tags: jquery, web, odoo

How to find max date in string. I try but not working.
My string is `2018年07月29日2018年07月24日2018年06月24日` 
How to find max date?
My code is:

```
var test = $(".deadline_class").text();

            var data = test
            var dates = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            {
                dates.push(new Date(data[i][0]));
            }

            var maxDate=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,dates));
            alert(maxDate);
```

Help, i need any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array to do this. So you need to split your string with some unique keyword like below i did with comma(,)

```
var test = "2018/07/29,2018/07/24,2018/06/24";
test = test.split(",")

            var data = test
            var dates = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            {
                dates.push(new Date(data[i][0]));
            }

            var maxDate=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,dates));
            alert(maxDate);
```